# Cannot fix vlcj load library 'libvlc'

Tags: java, vlcj

i am using netbeans to use vlcj jar my jdk is *jdk-7u45-windows-x64* and my *vlc is 64b* i  installed the library by going to libraries then right Click on the libraries file then add jar/folder and i added the file i download it from here [file link](https://code.google.com/p/vlcj/downloads/list) the file name *vlcj-3.0.0-dist.zip* i unzip it then add it by select them all the code for test is this

```
    package translater;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import com.sun.jna.Native;


/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class Translater {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuiClass is = new GuiClass("AnimeFactor");
        is.setVisible(true);

        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);


    }

}
```

the error message is this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc': JNA native support (win32-amd64/libvlc.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\isslam\Desktop\vlcj-2.4.1-dist\vlcj-2.4.1\jna-3.5.2.jar;C:\Users\isslam\Desktop\vlcj-2.4.1-dist\vlcj-2.4.1\platform-3.5.2.jar;C:\Users\isslam\Desktop\vlcj-2.4.1-dist\vlcj-2.4.1\vlcj-2.4.1.jar;C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\translater\build\classes)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:220)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:322)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:142)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:387)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:366)
at translater.Translater.main(Translater.java:27)
```

Answer (score 10):

vlcj has a dependency on JNA.

You therefore need to add the [JNA](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.java.dev.jna%7Cjna%7C4.0.0%7Cjar) and [JNA Platform](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.java.dev.jna%7Cjna-platform%7C4.0.0%7Cjar) jar files to your project. How you do this depends on your own project and the IDE your are using. The most basic way to do this is to download the jar files from the links [[1]](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.java.dev.jna%7Cjna%7C4.0.0%7Cjar) and [[2]](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.java.dev.jna%7Cjna-platform%7C4.0.0%7Cjar) and copy them to the same directory that contains the vlcj jar file.

The manifest class path declared inside the vlcj jar file refers to these JNA jars - this means that you should just need to make sure the jar files are copied to the correct place in your project, you should not have to explicitly add them to your project class path.

My view is it's simpler if you use Maven, but anyway...

After you have installed the libraries correctly, your next problem is get your JVM to load the native libraries.

You can get an UnsatisfiedLinkError for a number of reasons, the most common being:

1. The shared object (DLL) you are trying to load simply could not be found;
2. You are trying to mix CPU architectures, i.e. your JVM is 64-bit, but your native libraries are 32-bit (or vice versa). This can *never* work.

When loading a native library with JNA, there are a number of ways to set the search path...

This is explained in [[3]](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html), but to summarise here the simplest way is to add some code like this to your application:

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "the-directory");
```

This statement tells JNA to look in a particular directory to find the LibVLC shared objects (DLLs on Windows).

You replace the literal string "the-directory" with the full path to the directory on your disk that contains the libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll files (or equivalent .so files if you're on Linux).

There is no 64-bit or 32-bit version of vlcj - it's just platform independant Java.

[1]: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.java.dev.jna%7Cjna%7C4.0.0%7Cjar

[2]: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.java.dev.jna%7Cjna-platform%7C4.0.0%7Cjar

[3]: http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html

The above dependencies (and links to the artefacts) are correct if you are using vlcj 3.0.0 or later. If you are using an earlier version of vlcj such as 2.4.1, then you need to use JNA and JNA Platform version 3.5.2 instead of 4.0.0.

Comment: sorry can you give me more information about this it's my first application

Comment: can you tell me what i should do with this 2 site you give to me

Comment: JNA [1] and JNA Platform [2] they are their in the library file

Comment: where can i find vlcj 64b because my jdk is jdk-7u45-windows-x64 and my system is 64b and my vlc player is 64xb

Comment: There is no such thing as a 32-bit or 64-bit vlcj. The only things that have to match CPU architectures are the JVM and the vlc native libraries.

Comment: how to know if my jvm are 64 or not

Comment: Go to a terminal/console window and type "java -version" or check your Netbeans JDK configuration.

Answer (score 0):

right but my problem was with the jvm it was i think 32b so i change it by downloade it form here [java jvm](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) this page have the 32 and 64 type

Comment: If your problem was with the mismatched JVM architecture, like the other answer suggested, maybe you should accept that answer to close this question off.